# Java generic type EMPTY vs null

Tags: java, generics

I am storing data in an array of generic type `<E>` and need to mark some cells in that array as empty. I cannot use `null` because null is a valid entry that needs to be distinguishable from an empty cell.
What is the best way of making this distinction? I would like to avoid using other data structures such as a list containing the indices of `"empty"` cells.

In the case of an `Object` array I would simply create a dummy instance:

```
Object EMPTY = new Object();
```

and then mark empty cells using:

```
array[emptyIndex] = EMPTY;
```

As far as I know I cannot create an instance of *generic type E* to be used as an `"EMPTY"` marker though. Is there another way of creating an empty marker or are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Using `null` as actual values is utterly dangerous, and you are advised to reconsider. Regardless, have a look at `Optional`.

Comment: @E_net4 `Optional` can not contain `null`.

Comment: Do not use type `E`, but something that is actually suitable for your needs. You may want to write a wrapper class that encapsulates `E`.

Comment: @JornVernee Thus why I invite the OP to reconsider.

Comment: How are you creating this generic array, given that in an array creation expression for an array of a _ClassOrInterfaceType_, "It is a compile-time error if the _ClassOrInterfaceType_ does not denote a reifiable type (§4.7)" (JLS §15.10.1)?

Comment: @LewBloch I'm actually using `ArrayList<E>` but tried to keep unnecessary details out of the question.

Comment: That's a necessary detail, since your dissembling contributed to confusion rather than clarity. It's better for all if you stick with the truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know I cannot create an instance of *generic type E* to be used as an `"EMPTY"` marker though.

Supposing that you have no information about `E`, such as a lower type bound or its `Class` object, you are correct.  You cannot create an instance.  You could ask the user to provide one to you for the purpose, but that seems both inconvenient and potentially dangerous.

> Is there another way of creating an empty marker or are there any alternative solutions?

If the <s>array</s> `List` must in fact *be* a<s>n array</s> `List`, and if it must have generic element type `E` about which you have no specific knowledge, and if you cannot use `null` values to represent empty positions, then you've specified yourself into a corner.  Something has got to give.

Some possibilities include

- Use a `Map` with `Integer` keys instead of a<s>n array</s> `List`, and model empty elements as completely unmapped.  Then you can then use `Map.contains()` to determine whether a given index corresponds to an empty element.
- Use a `List` whose elements are of some wrapper type containing an `E` and an `isEmpty` flag or similar.
- Use a `List` of wrapper objects with no flag; represent empty elements as `null`, and non-empty `null` elements as wrappers *containing* `null`.
- Abandon type safety and force a plain `Object` into the <s>array</s> `List` as your "Empty" object.  That should be ok at run time as long as `E` does not have an upper type bound.

Answer (score 0):

In java there is no Empty marker.
Often, `null` is used to indicate empty.

Since this will not work for you,
you will need to create your own Empty marker.

The technique you mention is fine.

Another technique is define a Cell class much like this:

```
public class Cell
{
    private boolean empty;
    private Object data;

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return empty;
    }

    public void setEmpty()
    {
        empty = true;
    }

    public void setNotEmpty()
    {
        empty = false;
    }

    // set and get data.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrapper as described in the other answer is the best solution.

If you want to use the `EMPTY` marker and absolutely don't want to use wrappers, or other/additional data structures, then you'll have to resort to some dirty tricks.
You *could* do the following but I would not recommend it.

Let the user pass the `class` of the generic type in the constructor of your data structure. By doing this you get the type you need for your `EMPTY` instance. You can't simply create an instance using reflections though, since you don't know if instantiating the class has any site effects. To solve this problem you can use a library like [objenesis](http://objenesis.org/), which bypasses any constructors and allows you to instantiate objects without side effects.